# How to run a python module with -m from windows command line

Tags: python, windows, command-line, module

Basically I am trying to run a python module from the windows command line as follows.

```
> start /path_to_python_env/python.exe /path_to_module/ -m moduleName
```

I have also tried

```
> start /path_to_python_env/python.exe -m moduleName
```

which has also not worked. I do know that you can use `python -m module` from within a python environment, but I am specifically trying to do this from the windows command line. I am doing this because I have a python program I run as a module, and I'd like to analyze it in intel gpa, and I figure if I can figure out this command I can probably get it to work in gpa either by passing arguments or writing a wrapper exe to run the command for me.

Comment: try  `/path_to_python_env/python.exe /path_to_module/ -m moduleName`

Comment: that worked. I am now realizing the larger issue is how my module is written, but thank you.